# Possible to normalize image in Java in less than 2 passes?

Tags: java, image, optimization, normalization

I want to normalize an image - divide each color in the image by the darkest observed one. Currently, I am doing this by looping twice through the image: once to pick the darkest overall color, and then once to divide each color by that.

I can't help feeling that there has to be a more efficient way to do this. I'm relatively new to image processing in general - am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider image that has only one #000000 black pixel. Your first pass will fail with division by zero. You should read image format specification and look for used palette or any useful data and use this formula:

```
new_color=(old_color-OLD_MIN)*(NEW_MAX-NEW_MIN)/(OLD_MAX-OLD_MIN)+NEW_MIN
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are iterating through the loop the first time, you could make a copy of each color (lets call it copyOfImage array). Keep track of the darkest observed color so far and its index. After making a copy of each color as you are iterating through the loop, divide this color in the original image by the darkest color observed so far. When you find a new darkest color, you replace the old one and also keep track of the new darkest color's index.

When you reach the end of the first iteration of the image, each color in the original image will have been divided by the darkest color that was known at the time that we reached that color. Also, you will have the index of where the darkest color was found (lets call it darkestColorIndex) and the darkest color and a copy of the image before you edited it.

Now from darkestColorIndex to the end of the image will be correctly edited as all colors from darkestColorIndex until the end of the image will have been divided by the correct darkest color. However, you still have to edit 0 to darkestColorIndex. Therefore from 0 to darkestColorIndex, replace originalImage[i] with copyOfImage[i]/darkestColor (where i is the current index).

You increase the space complexity by the size of the image and the algorithm may still have to iterate through the image at a maximum of 2 times if the darkest color was found at the last index of the image. However if it was found in the first index, it would only have to iterate through it 1 time. On average it will probably have to iterate through the image 1.5 times.